# Trying to display ejs file but it displays the index.html instead

Tags: express, ejs

I'm using EJS for the first and I'm a bit confused. What's happening is that I have a list.ejs file created inside my views file. And a index.html outside I'm using a else if statement to do the logical thinking to the render my EJS file answer but when I call the res.render if I have the index.html, it displays it instead of my list.EJS, there are no errors or anything

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let today = new Date();
    let currentDay = today.getDay();
    let day = ""

    if (currentDay === 6 | currentDay === 0) {
        day = "Weekend"
    } else {
        day = "Weekday!"
    }
    res.render('list', {dayOfWeek: day})

})


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

list.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To Do List</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>To Do List</h1>
    <h2>It's a <%=dayOfWeek%>
    </h2>
</body>

</html>
```

The index.html is just a h1 Send Help..

What am I doing wrong?
I removed the index.html file and it works but it shouldn't be like that... Right?

Comment: Turns out I started playing around and it was the 
```app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```
I deleted it and it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code:

```js
const path=require("path");
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname));
```

Comment: if you store your .ejs files in a folder named as "views" , you don't need to write directory. it will defaultly check your "views" folder. So app.set('views'); this fill be enough.